# Notation of coordinate functions on manifolds

Tags: notation, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm confused about the notation used to represent the so called "local coordinates" when dealing with differential manifolds. As an example, I was given an exercise to prove that $S^{n-1}$ is a submanifold of dimension $n-1$ of $\mathbb{R^n}$, I did the following:

Let $F: \mathbb{R^n} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be given by $F((x^1)^2 + (x^2)^2 + ... + (x^n)^2 - 1)$. Then we have that $F^{-1}(0) = S^{n-1}$. Here the $x^i = x^i(p)$ are the coordinate functions of a point $p \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Now in order to show that $0$ is a regular value, I compute that the derivative (given by the Jacobian) of the map is surjective. The Jacobian is the row matrix:
$$DF = (2x^1 \ 2x^2 ... \ 2x^n)$$.

Now from linear algebra I know that a linear a transformation $t$ is onto iff $Ker(t) = \{0\}$. In this case we have that the only possible way the following equation holds:
$$(2x^1 \ 2x^2 ... \ 2x^n) \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{n}
         \end{bmatrix} = 0$$
is if the $p = 0$. Thus I conclude that the linear transformation is surjective. Then by the regular value theorem we have that $S^{n-1}$ is a regular submanifold of $R^n$.
Now main confusion arise when thinking about the coordinate functions in the Jacobian matrix. For example if I have the vector $\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0 \\
           \vdots \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}$, does the Jacobian send this vector to $2x^1$ or to $2$, because if it's first case then how is that a real number? Also would it be more correct to write the Jacobian as $(2 \ 2 \ ... 2)$ or even $(2x^1(p) \ 2x^2(p) ... \ 2x^n (p))$? In other words what is the meaning of writing the coordinate functions in the Jacobian as above?

Comment: You first have to *evaluate* the Jacobian at some point $ p $ where it is defined---*then* apply it to (take the dot product with) a vector to get a real number.

Comment: This observation is important because, as you correctly observed $ DF = (2x^1, \ldots 2x^n) $, which is in fact zero (not surjective) at $ p = \mathbf{0} $.  You should point out that this point $ p $ is not on your level-set, so the "regular value theorem", as you call it, implies you have a manifold.